# How to change an image on tab control without flickering

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I put an image on the header of the C# TabControl. I wanna change the image when cursor hovering over it.
[app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQx7F.jpg)
Now I call Control.Refresh method like this:

```
TabControl tabControl1 = new TabControl();

[...]

private void tabControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
[...]

    tabControl1.Refresh();
}

private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(imagefile, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);

[...]
}
```

By using a flag, Refresh method is called when cursor is about to be put over the image and going away from it, that is to say, Refresh method is not called many times in a row.
In this way, the image successfully changes, but often flickers.
How can I change it without flickering? Any Ideas?

Comment: Probably need to see more of the drawitem routine..

Comment: 1) Use Refresh only if Invalidate is not working. 2) if necessary use a doublebuffered Tab control: `class DrawTab : TabControl
    {
        public DrawTab()      { DoubleBuffered = true;  }
    }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TabControl` is a special one and you cannot turn on double buffering on it. It is because it requests all of the child elements of the active tab to draw themselves onto its content. Unfortunately this affects the tabs as well even if you do not want to customize the page drawings but the tabs only.

However, you can do some tricks to minimize the flickering:

**1. Never use `Refresh()`**

The `Refresh()` method forces the whole control to be re-drawn immediately, no matter what are you doing at the moment. Instead, use `Invalidate` to mark the control invalid, so it will be repainted along with the other invalid controls in a dedicated refreshing session.

**2. Make the complete form double buffered**

Though `TabControl` does not support double buffering, you can make the whole `Form` double buffered, which can reduce flickering.

Just override `CreateParams` in your form to do so:

```
private const int WS_EX_COMPOSITED = 0x02000000;

protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_COMPOSITED;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

**3. Invalidate only the invalid regions**

If you invalidate the whole `TabControl`, it will be completely repainted along with its children. But you want to invalidate some 16x16 pixels rectangle in the tab so you can spare the refreshing of the whole control.

```
private int hoveredIndex = -1;
private Size imageSize = new Size(16, 16);

private void TabControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabPages.Count; i++)
    {
        Rectangle rect = tabControl1.GetTabRect(i);
        Rectangle closeButton = GetImageLocation(rect);
        if (closeButton.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            if (hoveredIndex != i)
            {
                hoveredIndex = i;
                tabControl1.Invalidate(rect);
            }
        }
        else if (hoveredIndex == i)
        {
            tabControl1.Invalidate(tabControl1.GetTabRect(hoveredIndex));
            hoveredIndex = -1;
        }
    }
}

private void TabControl1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (hoveredIndex != -1)
    {
        tabControl1.Invalidate(tabControl1.GetTabRect(hoveredIndex));
        hoveredIndex = -1;
    }
}

private Rectangle GetImageLocation(Rectangle rect)
{
    return new Rectangle(rect.Right - imageSize.Width, rect.Top, imageSize.Width, imageSize.Height);
}

private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    Image image = e.Index == hoveredIndex ? imageHovered : imageNormal;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, GetImageLocation(e.Bounds));
}
```

Comment: The 1st point is correct and is probably good enough. The rest seems dubious: 2) Doublebuffering the Form will not double-buffer any nested controls. Your code enforces double-buffering all all the nested controls even where it is not needed at all. 3) Invalidating partial controls makes a difference very very rarely. Usually the System does a better job. - If point 1) doesn't do, he could  __subclass__ the `Tab` control itself and set ´DoubleBuffered` on for it..

Answer (score 1):

You need double buffer for this.

"Double Buffer is a technique where we draw all our graphic needs to an image stored in the memory (buffer) and after we are done with all our drawing needs we a draw a complete image from the memory onto the screen. This concentrates the drawing to the screen (an operation that badly effects the performance of the application) to a single operation rather than many small ones."

See https://www.codeproject.com/kb/graphics/doublebuffering.aspx